# "Bad_pool_caller" bluescreen. How to figure out what's causing it

Tags: windows-8, bsod

I bought my HP 15-r085no in September last year. After a while, I got a few bluescreens with the accompanying horrible sound. There was two (I think) different bluescreens, where one of them was with the message "Bad_pool_caller". I cant remember the other one.

I updated the graphic driver. I don't know if that was what fixed it, but at least it didn't happen again - until now.

One day at the endo of last week, I had two bluescreens with "bad_pool_caller". The day after I had none. I updated my graphics driver once more. Sunday and Monday passed with no bluescreens. During the last 30 minutes, I've gotten two more bluescreen of the same type, while typing a question on the LaTeX pages and typing this question.

What can be causing this bluescreen? Is it software or hardware related? How do I troubleshoot this? The bluescreens says something about collecting some error info. Can this information be helpful? Where do I find it?

Bluescreen pictures:
[image: bluescreen WSOD]

Screendump from BlueScreenView:
[image: WSOD blue screen dump table]

**EDIT:** Added log from BlueScreenView
**EDIT 2:** Can OneDrive for business be causing the trouble? I'm at least having a lot of trouble with it!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.
A bluescreen can have a lot of different reasons, caused both by software and hardware issues. 
When you get a bluescreen, windows usually creates a dump file which contains information about why the bluescreen appeared.
Can you give us some information about this dump file by using e.g. Bluescreenview (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)?

Comment: @Zaheylu: Thank you for your comment. Please see the updated question for information on the dump file.

Comment: Does this happen if you use Autoruns and not load any device drivers except for your display drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound: I do not fully understand your comment. I haven't manually disabled (or unloaded) any device drivers.

Comment: Ramhound is talking about disabling all not vitally needed drivers using the tool 'autoruns' which is a microsoft system utility. You can obtain autoruns from the windows sysinternals web site: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Occasional BSOD at Windows 8 cold boot](http://superuser.com/questions/526632/occasional-bsod-at-windows-8-cold-boot)

Comment: activate driver verifier (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you get new crashes, share the new dmps from C:\Windows\Minidump